# how to get html hidden value in behind code?

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net

I have a variable to catch the height of screen when i click the button,but none of the method from below got null value. I don't know the right one to get it,could someone please help me? THANKS!!

### HTML

```
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function abc()
        {
            //method 1
            var h = $("<%= hf_height.Value %>");
            //method 2
            var h = $("<%= hf_height.ClientID %>").val();
            //method 3
            var h = $("#height").val();

            h = $(window).height();
        }
    </script>
    <asp:Button ID="code_s_button" runat="server" Text="Search Code" 
        onclick="code_s_button_Click" onclientclick="abc()" />

    <asp:HiddenField ID="hf_height" runat="server"/>

    <input type="hidden" id="height"/> 
    //test both with runat="server" and no runat="server"
</Content>
```

### Code Behind

```
protected void code_s_button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    hf_height.Value = ((HiddenField)Page.FindControl("height")).ToString(); // for method 3
    Alert.Show(hf_height.Value);
}
```

Comment: Please check if EnableViewState is false??

Comment: you are not assigning value to hidden field, you are just reading value from them, also follow javascript:MethodName(); pattern for javascript calls

Comment: EnableViewState of hiddenfield value is "true"

Comment: how to edit code to write value instead of reading? Vinay Pandey

Comment: have a look at my answer. It will help you to solve your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try below code (I have tested it and working fine) :

**ASPX Page**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function abc() {
        $("#<%=height.ClientID%>").val($(window).height()); 
    }
</script>

<asp:Button ID="code_s_button" runat="server" Text="Search Code"
    OnClick="code_s_button_Click" OnClientClick="abc()" />

<asp:HiddenField ID="hf_height" runat="server" />

<input type="hidden" id="height" runat="server" />
```

**Code Behind :**

```
protected void code_s_button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var height = this.height.Value;
}
```

**Note :**  What I have found wrong in your javascript code is **missing '#'**

Comment: Hope you like the provided solution. Don't forget to upvote and mark it as an answer. so that it may help to other developer's as well.

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your javascript `abc()` function

```
var h = document.getElementById('<%=hf_height.ClientID %>').value;

h = $(window).height();
```

In your code behind you can access the hidden field like below,

```
protected void code_s_button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    hf_height.Value = this.height.Value;
    Alert.Show(hf_height.Value);
}
```

Comment: thanks for the reply.I tested ,but behindcode 'hf_height.Value' return null value